# Jose4j - Can we use same RsaJsonWebKey for all the users to construct jwt

Tags: rsa, jwt, digital-signature

Can we use same RsaJsonWebKey for all the users to construct jwt?

What issues we may encounter if we take this approach?

In my opinion, since claims differ for each client the final jwt should be different for each user and should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to use the same  key for all JWTs issued. It would be possible to have a key per user but it is not practical:

- require storage  of keys in ddbb, both public and private
- publish or distribute public keys
- each request require database access to load user's public key in order to verify the signature

This solution misses some of the advantages of JWT. I can not find a scenario where it's useful

Note: if we talk about authentication in a API where tokens are issued by client, then each client will have their own private key